# Cordova - changing badge number on Android devices in the background, when notification has been received

Tags: android, cordova, background, notifications, badge

I have a joomla back end, and I have implemented the jBackEnd plugin to feed my app with REST data. But that is beside the point. jBackEnd also has support for GCM and APN notifications, which I use to send a notification to my cordova app users (android only) every time a new article has been added.

The problem is - I have tried everything, notifications work - using the pushplugin for cordova, the phone vibrates, the sound is there, basically the notification is working. However, I cannot update the badge number when the application is in the background, because the on notification event is not being triggered.

As I understand, I cannot run javascript code in the background (unless I use a plugin that disables sleep for applications when pressing the home button - something I have tried, and it's still not working), and that makes sense - it's a webview after all. However, if I cannot listen for the on notification event, what is there to do ?

No answer I have found on the web helped. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

The code below can be found in an `$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {` block, inside the run function (angular).

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "36070516254",
        },
        "ios": {
            "alert": "true",
            "badge": "true",
            "sound": "true"
        }
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        var device_token = data.registrationId;
        GcmService.registerClient(device_token, function(data) {
            console.info('Registered !', data);
            // # Start the scheduler
        }, function(status) {
            console.error('After registering with the joomla thing !');
        });
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.info('!!! Information received : ', data);
        try {
                push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function(s) {
                    console.info('Badge success', s);
                }, function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }, badgeCounter++);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've installed the newest version of the push-plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and you send the param (server side) "badge" in the data array to GCM, the badge will be updated on notification.

Also you need to set the badge param true in your app:

```
push = PushNotification.init
({android: {
senderID: "xxxxxxxx",
badge: "true"
});
```

That did the trick for me at least.